# jQuery/javascript: webkit clearTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

On the back of my previous question I am having some trouble with the following code in webkit browsers Safari and Chrome: -

```
// Textarea focus out event.
var renderHandler;


$("textarea").live('focusout', function (e) {
   var currentNote = this;
   renderHandler = setTimeout( function(){ renderNote(currentNote); }, 100);
});

// handle exceptions
$('.textEdit').live('focusin', function (e) {
   clearTimeout(renderHandler);

});



function renderNote( note ){
var itemContent = $(note).val();
    itemContent = htmlStrip(itemContent);
    itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"); // New lines
    //itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\s/g, " &nbsp;"); // Spaces

// Formatting replacements
itemContent = itemContent
    .replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<b>")
    .replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</b>")
    .replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<i>")
    .replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</i>")
    .replace(/\[s\]/gi, "<s>")
    .replace(/\[\/s\]/gi, "</s>");

$(note).replaceWith("<p class='notes'>"+ itemContent +"</p>");
}
```

In firefox latest clearTimeout on renderHandler prevents the function 'renderNote' from being called which allows me to handle exceptions on the focusout event. However in webkit browsers renderNote is called regardless.

I have tried return, return false, preventDefault, stopPropagation, break but no joy. Anyone come across this before?

Heres a link: http://www.kryptonite-dove.com/sandbox/animate

If you double click on the body, then click on the body of the note you can see it in action.

Comment: Working fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TsuZn/

Comment: Actually, I see that the above code is part of `functionality.js`. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TsuZn/1/

Comment: Same difference mate they both showed a working example :)

Comment: Yes, but the first couldn't be edited by an interested SOer, since it was contained in that `.ready()` block.

Comment: Is what you're trying for something that will block a render if someone is clicking one of the text styles (strikethrough, bold, italic)?

Comment: Yes exactly, if you look at the behavior in ff when you click in the note it presents a textarea you can type into, if you select some text and click on one of the bold strikethrough or italics it wraps the select in bb tags. BUT you can still type in the textarea. When you click on anything other than those with the class of .textEdit it changes what you entered back to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, `$.live()` is deprecated; `$.on()` or `$.delegate()` should be used instead. For some reason, proper use of either of these continues to evade me, so I can't propose how to do this, but you should consider avoiding `$.live()`, as it will eventually be removed and is, to wit, a performance problem.

From what I can tell, the line:

```
$('.textEdit').live('focusin', function (e) {
```

Never runs in Chrome. That's ok, because it seems like

```
$('.textEdit').live('click', function (e) {
```

Should work just fine.

I would modify your approach and use a block variable as in well, instead of canceling the timeout. For instance:

```
var renderHandler,
    blockRender = false;

$("textarea").live('focusout', function (e) {
    var currentNote = this;
    renderHandler = setTimeout(function(){ 
        renderNote(currentNote); 
    }, 100);
});

$('.textEdit').live('click', function (e) {
    blockRender = true;
});
```

And then in `renderNote()`:

```
function renderNote( note ){
    var itemContent = $(note).val();

    if (blockRender) {
        blockRender = false;
        return false;
    }

    itemContent = htmlStrip(itemContent);
    itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");

    itemContent = itemContent
        .replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<b>")
        .replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</b>")
        .replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<i>")
        .replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</i>")
        .replace(/\[s\]/gi, "<s>")
        .replace(/\[\/s\]/gi, "</s>");

    $(note).replaceWith("<p class='notes'>"+ itemContent +"</p>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TsuZn/3/

Comment: "proper use of either of these continues to evade me"... I thought I must be the only one. It just never seems to work when used as a "live" replacement e.g. `$('body').on('event','selector',func);`. Still haven't figured out if I'm being stupid or there's something not right with it..

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161691/replacing-jquery-live-with-jquery-on-doesnt-work

Comment: @KryponiteDove, actually the examples given by that answer are indeed useful. The documentation on jquery.com is awful and doesn't even have a basic example of replacing "live". Thanks for the link.

Comment: @KryptoniteDove - I got a wild hair and decided to rewrite the entire thing (JS-wise). The only thing I'm noticing right now is that it doesn't handle going directly from the note edit to the title edit cleanly (which I changed to double clicks for both entries). Let me know what you think: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kS3FG/

Comment: Yeah I see that too Jared, to be honest your code looks a LOT better than mine, cleaner and neater and not reliant on depreciated events ;) will have a look through it and see what I can learn! thanks very much!