# summernote - update code when in HTML view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

I am using [Summernote](http://summernote.org/#/) WYSIWYG editor and I'm stuck in this issue:
Every time the view changes from Rich Text to HTML I want to make some calculations and update the editors content.
But when the editor changes from Rich Text to HTML [.code()](http://summernote.org/#/features#api-code) doesn't seem to work...
After a while I realised that when the editor is in HTML mode, `.code()` does not work at all - that's why when pressing "codeview" button from text to html doesn't work...

See this feedle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpp1Lmhn/4/ (press the "Update" button when in Rich Text and then when in HTML mode)

So the question is:
**Is there a way to update the editor's content when in HTML view?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the funny little change you have to make is change ".live" to ".on". [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161691/replacing-jquery-live-with-jquery-on-doesnt-work) is a link to discussion on the significance of that little change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editor').summernote({
        height:200,
        toolbar: [ ['text', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
                    ['misc', ['codeview']]
                ]
    });

    $('[data-event="codeview"]').on('click', function(){
        $('#editor').code($('#editor').code()+'a');
    });

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#editor').code($('#editor').code()+'a');
    });
});
```

and you can visit the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2tnua16k/